# Confused with Containers & Docker Layer Representation

Tags: docker, containers

This is a popular representation of showing containers running on top of Docker layer and which in turn runs on Host Operating System ( Kernel)[image: Containers Diagram]

But I read on this article That Containers essentially run on Kernel and not on docker.

http://crunchtools.com/containers-dont-run-on-docker/

[image: How actually Containers run on Host]

I am now confused which representation is the correct representation. To start stop containers, we certainly need Docker or container Engine but once it is started, it runs on Linux Kernel. I tend to agree on the second representation. Please throw some light on this aspect.

Comment: The containers share the Host's kernel, that is correct. A container is essentially "only" an environment on the host, isolated from the actual host processes. I recommend watching [Liz Rice explaining containers from scratch on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSlheqvaRso). In this video, she shows how to "create" a simple container with a handfull of kernel methods.

Comment: Figure 1 matches my understanding the best. There is a Docker virtualization layer between the container and the host. That layer, among other things, prevents the container from doing certain things on the host. This layer also enables stuff like mapping file system locations inside the container to volumes or file system locations on the host.

Comment: "*There is a Docker virtualization layer between the container and the host.*" - Nope, this is - [w.l.o.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) - not true. The "virtualization layer" is realized through kernel function calls (namely chroot, namespaces and cgroups)

Comment: @Turing85 You seem to have a better grasp of the exact terms than I do. But there is something between the container and the host which isn't there when you run your application directly on the host. When making a drawing of the runtime environment, I think it makes sense to draw that 'something'.

Comment: @HansKilian As I said: the "something" are some kernel function calls. They are there and used in any linux-based system. For containerization, they are used in a cleverly orchestrated way to achieve what we know as "containers". The core concepts, hohwever, are pretty old (namespaces date back to 2002, cgroups to 2007). If you want to know some details, I highly recommend Liz Rice's talk I linked in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858164/confused-with-containers-docker-layer-representation?noredirect=1#comment121692863_68858164).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both diagrams are correct to some extent. However, they give **different bird-eye perspectives** on the same problem.

Having such high-level diagrams, it's indeed hard to judge *what exactly runs a container*. Somewhat closer to real decomposition actually looks as follows:

[image]

Note that on the diagram above, every box represents a regular Linux process on the host machine. Thus, `dockerd`, `containerd`, and the containers themselves are no different in that regard. Containers are actually regular Linux processes. They are just slightly more isolated and restricted than others.

What makes containers distinct from the rest of the processes is the fact that Docker (by means of its subcomponents) puts these processes into virtualized sandboxes. These boxes from the inside look like dedicated instances of an OS to those processes. And that's where the kernel plays the crucial role - it provides all the OS-level virtualization capabilities (such as namespaces, virtual network devices, etc.) to create such boxes. Or jails, if you will.

You can find more technical details on container managers, runtimes, and shims in this series of articles:

- [conman - [the] container manager: inception](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/conman-the-container-manager-inception/)
- [Implementing Container Runtime Shim: runc](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/implementing-container-runtime-shim/)
- [Implementing Container Runtime Shim: First Code](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/implementing-container-runtime-shim-2/)

Answer (score 0):

The right representation is the second one.

The container paradigm is based on a specific OS implementation of the same concept: Linux uses [User Namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), Windows uses [Hyper-V](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/), and so on... The above technologies allow you to create containers in terms of processes isolation which act like an OS independent instance.

**Docker**, **LXC**, and any other, are like orchestrators which allow users to manage containers by **APIs** or a **CLI**.

Comment: IIRC, Hyper-V is only used to start a virtualized linux under windows (same with WSL2). From there on, the containers, again, work with namespaces, cgroups, ... in the virtualized linux.

Answer (score 0):

A major benefit of containers over virtual machines is that containers are often described as "lightweight".

Containers achieve this by not starting a full independent environment, but rather use the host's environment - namely the kernel. This is achieved by process isolation (through [linux namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces), dating back to 2002) and separate resource limitation (through [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), dating back to 2007). We can make this even visible by starting a container on a host and, while the container is running, list all processes on the host (e.g. through `ps aux`). We will see the processes in the container. We can, if we have the permissions, even kill those processes and (if we kill the right one, i.e. the entrypoint) thus kill the container.

There is a [nice talk from Liz Rice on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSlheqvaRso) where they explain and show how a rudimentary container can be built through system kernel calls (they use `golang` in the demonstration, but we can re-write all those calls to direct kernel calls and, for example, bake them in a `.sh` script if we so desire).

If we draw parallels to programming, we could say that the docker API is a facade for already existing functionality. I would say that the 2nd image represents more closely as to what I have described.

If our docker-host is a non-linux based system (MacOS, Windows), then we need a way to provide a base-host with a kernel for the container runtime. For windows, we can achieve this either through [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) or [WSL2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux#WSL_2). For MacOS, the [hypervisor.framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hypervisor) is used to run a linux virtual machine. In this scenario, a combination of the 1st and 2nd image wouldl best describe the setup.